# Apache Spark: How can I improve FP-Growth calculation speed by limiting results

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark

recently I am trying to implement FP-Growth via Apache Spark to evaluate data. The data at hand is basically shopping-cart data, with a customer and a product.
As the datasets are very complex, the calculation of the frequentItemsets takes very long. So i decided to try and filter the results by putting a max. length for the frequentItemsets like this:

```
//To do run FPGrowthTest 

FPGrowth fpg = new FPGrowth().setMinSupport(minSupport).setNumPartitions(12);

// run the model on the values which are the products for each custome
JavaRDD<Iterable<String>> groupByValues = groupsForProduct.values();

FPGrowthModel<String> model = fpg.run(groupByValues);

double minConfidence = 0.3;

JavaRDD<FreqItemset<String>> filteredmodel = model.freqItemsets().toJavaRDD()
      .filter(new Function<FreqItemset<String>, Boolean>(){
            public Boolean call(FreqItemset<String> fi){
                if (fi.javaItems().size() <= 5){
                    return true;}
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        });


filteredmodel.map(new Function<FPGrowth.FreqItemset<String>, String>() {        
            @Override public String call(FPGrowth.FreqItemset<String> fi) {
                return fi.javaItems() + " -> " + fi.freq();
            }
        }).saveAsTextFile(
            <path>);

AssociationRules ar = new AssociationRules();
ar.setMinConfidence(minConfidence);
ar.run(filteredmodel).saveAsTextFile(<path>);
```

I am trying to go through the data product by product to reduce the tree size of the FP-Growth algorithm step by step. Still for the first product my algorithm is running for one hour now and is still not finished and I am only running it on a small sample of the data. The program is not even completing the first step of creating all frequentItemsets, so I dont even get to see, if the AssociationRules results look as I want them to look.

Is there any way to reduce the treesize of the calculation without having to filter() the whole data? Am I doing something wrong and how can I improve the speed? There does not seem to be a function to limit frequentItemset results. Maybe is there any other solution to handle such complex datasets?

TL/DR: Is there a way to improve the FP-Growth algorithm by limiting frequentItemset results without filtering all the data?

Comment: What is `minSupport`?

Comment: As we are trying to do it product by product, the minSupport depends on the amounts of customers. Not sure if that makes sense if I put it so shortly. But to answer your question the minSupport for the first product iteration is 10/12=0.83.

Comment: It makes enough sense. Filtering `freqItemsets` is not a solution and AFAIK at this moment  FPGrowth cannot be configured to stop early. But it still doesn't really explain why it is so slow. With 0.83 support threshold it typically should converge pretty fast.

Comment: The thing is, as there are lots of products for one customer which increases complexity by a ton. And as we look at one product only, there is a very high probability that the values in these data pieces are similar, as most customers buy similar products, I guess. 

The result I had after one hour of processesing was a file about 20MB big, which is not very large. I guess this is due to the complex transformations that had to be undertaken.

Any ideas how I might get this one running faster? Is there a better way than groupByKey to sort the data?

Answer (score 0):

yeah the problem are the oulier transactions (the one you mention with lots of items). So I suggest you remove those, I hade the same issue. The average ticket had 5 items and I had just 2 transactions with 52 or 46 items and those made the process explode. Once I removed them I was able to run it without problem. So yeah that, remove outliers transactions and you should be good to go.